# How to disable paste option in menucontroller in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have to disable Paste option when user long press on UITextField.I have got this code but still it is not hiding Paste option.

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {

    if ( [UIMenuController sharedMenuController] )
    {
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;

    }
    return NO;  
}
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: By any chance are you using interface builder and forgot to change that instance to your custom class?

Comment: @borrrden NO there are views on single Viewcontroller w.r.t my conditions i m showing specific view

Comment: Then put a breakpoint there to confirm that this method is being called.

Comment: @borrrden yes it is being called

Comment: try to "include the exact same code in a subclass of UITextField and then use instances of that class" http://www.springtiger.co.uk/2011/11/17/disable-uimenucontroller-for-uitextfield-in-ios5/

Comment: you did something.. with PASTE option?

Comment: i did not get any solution on that still

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said in comments.. you need to "include the exact same code in a subclass of UITextField and then use instances of that class"

so.. create new file .. let's say TestPaste.. subclass of UITextField

[image]

put your code in implementation file (TextPaste.m)

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {

    if ( [UIMenuController sharedMenuController] )
    {
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;

    }
    return NO;  
}
```

now. go to your NIB/Storyboard, click on your UITextFiled and change the textview class to your TextPaste

[image]

Comment: This is an ugly hack. @Shubnank's solution should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Piya just check this below link :-

http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/04/12/iphone-disable-the-cutcopypaste-menu-on-uitextfield/

You can also check this code :-

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new Class-> subclass of UITextField .. then in your code/xib change the textview class to your Custom Class.. and the add the method in your custom TextField class

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

It will work then

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
@implementation UITextFiels (DisableCopyPaste)

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```