# how to disable UIMenuControll (cut,copy,paste,select all,delete) in UIviewController subclass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uimenucontroller

i have implemented many methods but paste doesn't hide. i am using Xcode Version 4.5.2

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    if (menuController) {
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;

    }
    return NO;  
}
```

every method is seems to fail working for me. can anybody help me on this? thanks in advance

Comment: try to subclass your outlets - check my example for UITextFields http://stackoverflow.com/a/14582785/1702413

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: in your controller's `viewDidLoad` method, set it to invisible.

```
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO];
```

If that does not work, I guess you are out of luck as it is part of the system. The only way I see is to **disable the user interaction** with objects that might trigger a context menu.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do these things to enable/disable UIMenuController items.

1. To show/hide the UIMenuController items, your view or view controller needs to implement `canBecomeFirstResponder`(returning YES/NO for Show/Hide).
2. You can also implement the `canPerformAction:withSender:` method of UIResponder to disable or enable user-interface commands {copy, select, select all, paste and etc} based on the context.
3. Or you can override the `Update` method of `UIMenuController` to handle the custom behavior of an individual item. For example, if the pasteboard holds no data of a compatible type, the `Paste` command would be disabled. So you may either force to show/hide the paste menu item by overriding this method.